# Remmina connected to Raspbian, will the session be kept even I disconnected

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, remmina

I just got my Ubuntu connected to my Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian)

Once connected, from the Remmina I saw a new Raspbian desktop which cannot be seen on Pi screen itself.

My question is, if I disconnected my current session, will the tasks running on Pi via this session be kept?

If yes, how can I verify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is it keeps the session even you closed Remmina client.

When using Remmina connected to Pi, you will see where you left on the same session.